# gprc client async response NodeJS

Tags: node.js, async-await, graphql, grpc, rpc

I'm trying to call a simple grpc request in a function but I don't know how to wait for the response and pass it outside the grpc call.

It should be something like that:

```
Client: (parent, args, context, info) =>{
      client.Get({thing, objects, properties}, function(err, response) {
            //how to return the response outside?
          });
      //await for the response function.
};
```

Is it possible to return the response in some way outside the client.Get function?
Does someone have some suggestions?
Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 10):

You have two ways:

1. Wrap the methods of gRPC from error first callback to promise by yourself.

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => client.Get({thing, objects, properties}, function(err, response) {
  if(err) {
    return reject(err)
  }
  resolve(response)        
}))
```

2. Use [grpc-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc-promise) to promisify the methods of gRPC client.

```js
const grpc_promise = require('grpc-promise');;
grpc_promise.promisifyAll(client);
```

Then, you can pass this promisified gRPC client to GraphQL context. (Guess you are using GraphQL based on the function signature).

Then you can return a promise in a GraphQL resolver.

```js
Client: (parent, args, context, info) =>{
  return context.client.Get({thing, objects, properties})
};
```